# Heart Rate in Python

Tags: python

I'm solving this problem on Kattis called Heart Rate.

Link to the problem: https://open.kattis.com/problems/heartrate

**ISSUE**: Getting an input with 2 different data types and manipulating them as such.

Here is my solution so far, but it only returns final answers in int data types when I think they're supposed to be floats.

```python
n = int(input())

for i in range(n):
    b,p = list(map(int, input().split(" ")))
    
    bpm = 60*b / p
    variance = 60 / p
    
    min_bpm = bpm - variance
    max_bpm = bpm + variance
    
    print(min_bpm, bpm, max_bpm)
```

The p and the final answers are supposed to be real numbers specified to 4 decimal places; while b is an int.

[image: Here is the expected input and output.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are mapping int type to all the values of list i.e b and p. Apply different type casting to them. You can do something like this,

```
b, p = input().split(" ")
b = int(b)
p = float(p)
```

For formatting to 4 decimal places you can use `"{:.4f}".format(var)`